# How can i parse this result from a fetch call EXpress NoseJs Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Here is the code of my script, it's in the index.html file, I know it's wrong to be there but first I'm trying to make it work, then I'll move it.

```
readOperaciones();
        
async function readOperaciones(){
            try{
                const listaOr = document.getElementById('listaOrdenada');

                const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/operaciones", {method: "GET"})
                const operaciones = await JSON.parse(result)
                //operaciones.forEach(t=>{


                    for (var i = 0; i < operaciones.length; i++) {
                    var row = operaciones[i];
                    console.log(row.codeemp);
}

                    /*tt = JSON.stringify(t);
                    const li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.textContent = tt.text;*/

                    /*t.forEach(cell=>{
                        const li = document.createElement("li")
                        li.textContent = cell.text;
                        li.id = cell.id;
                    })*/


                //})
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log("Error al leer las operaciones descriptas")
            }
        }
```

Here is the connecting with express

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const express = require ("express")

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())



const client = new Client({
  user: "postgres",
  password: "1234",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "webaduana",
})


app.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`))

app.get("/operaciones", async (req, res) => {
    const rows = await readAll();
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
})


async function readAll(){
    try{
        const results = await client.query("select * from operaciones")
        return results.rows;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        return [];
    }
}
```

I don't know if I need to put more information but my question about all this code is here
I've tried many ways of doing it but I can't get those results in an ol element.
It doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't print anything in the HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Add a .then to the fetch chain and print your results:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => {
    console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  ...
  ...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

you can use .json() method :

```
const fetched = await fetch("/url", {
  method: 'GET',
});

const fetchedJson: object = await fetched.json();

console.log(fetchedJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.

### Using Promises

The *fetch* response object inherently includes some methods that can help you to get a response in different forms such as `.json()`, `.text()`, and `.status`. [Learn more about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) So, if you simply want to parse the answer into a JSON object, you can do

```js
function doSomethingOnParsedJson(res) {
  // Do something on the response here...
}

function readOperacions() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/operaciones", {
    method: "GET",
  })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(doSomethingOnParsedJson) // Pass in a function without parentheses
     .catch(console.error);
}
```

It's cleaner if you define a separate function which performs the job you want to do on the *parsed response* and pass the function (without parentheses) to `then` but you can also go ahead and give it a function directly like:

```js
function readOperacions() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/operaciones", {
    method: "GET",
  })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(parsedResponse => {
       // do something...
     })
     .catch(console.error);
}
```

### Using Async/Await

You can also use the async/await feature to achieve that.

```js
function doSomethingOnParsedJson(res) {
  // Do something on the response here...
}

async function readOperacions() {
  try {
    // Get the response from the server.
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/operaciones", {
      method: "GET",
    });
  
    // Parse it into a JSON object.
    const parsedJson = res.json();

    // Do something on it.
    doSomethingOnParsedJson(parsedJson);
  } catch (error) {
    // Show an error if something unexpected happened.
  }
}
```

### Side Note

There is a neater way to send a JSON response in Express. You can use the `.json` method on the Express response object.

```js
app.get("/operaciones", async (req, res) => {
  const rows = await readAll();

  /* Don't do this!
  res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
  */

  /* Do this instead ;-) */
  res.json(rows);
})
```

Voila! It's that simple.